# Focusing on reviewing/moderation in areas in which I'm not clueless

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, moderation

When I (not frequently enough I'm sure) try to do some moderation/review work, I'm mostly given questions/answers on subject about which I know very little, or absolutely nothing. Now, sometimes I manage, but very often I don't. On the other hand, I very rarely get questions to work on which are, say, tagged with those tags for which I have a badge or a at-least-double-digit score.

Is this intentional? Can I do something about it (other than judicious skipping, which I avoid since I feel guilty for cherry-picking)? *Should* I do something about it?

Comment: See also [More aggressive tag match between reviewed question and reviewer activity](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/143854) on [meta.se].

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most review queues have a filter option, except Triage.

The filter can be found next to the title of the queue:

[image: queue filter]

You can enter up to three tags and for specific queues extra filters, for example close reasons.

You can also create bookmarks by adding the tag on the url like so:

> [`/review/close?filter-tags=godaddy`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=godaddy)

Another benefit is that audits are easier to spot when you use a filter, specially in the CVQ. When you see an Haskell question when filtered on GoDaddy you know something is up...

When you are presented with an review in a tag you're familiar with but can't make an informed decision, [there is no shame in using skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip). You're not cherry-picking, you're offering other reviewers their chance to review that task.

An other option when in doubt is to ask in a chatroom for advice. The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room exists for this reason. You'll find regulars there with both experience and mileage in all kind of reviewing and flagging. They also maintain additional userscripts to assist in moderation tasks, like a [CVQ keyboard shortcut script](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/CloseVoteShortcuts.user.js).

Comment: Why, does GoDaddy not support web applications developed in Haskell? :-)