# Moderating the [moderators], [moderation] and [moderator-abilities] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, meta

Here on Meta, we have a couple of closely related tags:

- [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) (93 questions)
- [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) (149 questions)
- [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) (19 questions)
- [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) (19 questions)

The tag excerpt for [moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderators/info) says:

> Questions about diamond (♦) moderators, their *powers*, and *actions* they have taken.

and the one for [moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderation/info) is not much different:

> This tag is for questions dealing with moderator *actions*, pages, *abilities* or decisions.

(emphasis mine). While the [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) wiki is clearly oriented towards ♦ moderators, a lot of its questions (e.g. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333370/do-we-need-coordinated-efforts-to-moderate-the-site), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333295/focusing-on-reviewing-moderation-in-areas-in-which-im-not-clueless)) are actually about *community* moderation. For new users, it's extra confusing: they often mistake users closing their question as ♦ moderators. Note that at the moment, the moderation tag wiki is clear about when to use either one:

> Questions should not use this tag if their question is about moderators themselves, rather than the actions they take/can take. For questions about moderators, use [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderators).

but this does not fit with the tag excerpt for [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators).

The [moderator-abilities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderator-abilities/info) tag excerpt says:

> a subset of privileges available to moderators and users with high reputation

this seems to be a combination of the 'abilities' part of [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) and the [10k-tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/10k-tools/info) tag. Meanwhile, the [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) tag doesn't even have a tag wiki.

#### My proposal

is to synonymize/burninate these four tags into two separate ones. The [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) tag should deal with ♦ moderators, their tools and actions, and the [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) should deal with *community* moderation (and maybe renamed as [community-moderation](/questions/tagged/community-moderation) to avoid confusion). The tag excerpts should clearly reflect that, e.g.

> Questions about diamond (♦) moderators, their powers, and actions they have taken. For questions about moderation by normal users, use the [community-moderation] tag instead.

---

> This tag is for questions dealing with moderating actions performed by and powers available to normal users, such as closing or deleting questions. For ♦ moderators, use the [moderators] tag instead.

This will require some retagging work, for questions about ♦ moderators which are now tagged [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) and vice versa. Also, questions currently tagged [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) and [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) can be retagged with either [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) or [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think these four tags should combine into one since there are very distinct things that a diamond moderator can do and a 10K+ user can do in terms of moderation.  It makes sense to me to have a tag to discuss powers/actions taken by a diamond moderator as opposed to community-driven moderation; the latter is much more in abundance and is too often conflated with the former.

To that end, I do see some deduplication that can occur.  Namely:

- [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) and [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) make sense to combine under one tag with the **explicit** proviso that questions should only be discussing diamond moderators.
- [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) should likely go under [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools); whatever question(s) that can fit under the 10K tool bucket should move and what questions can't should go underneath the <s>winner</s>Highlander of [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) and [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation)
- [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) *could* be merged with the Highlander but it does make *some* sense to explicitly call out diamond moderator tool sets, if only for bug reports and hiccups when they're used.

Comment: Would a new [community-moderation] tag make sense? I have the feeling that when discussing this topic, (Meta) veterans will use e.g. the [moderation] tag, while newbies generally tag such questions [closed-question], [deleted-question] etc. because they don't know *everybody* is a moderator, but not a ♦ one.

Comment: @Glorfindel:  On the surface I'm not opposed to that tag, but if we start lumping in question statuses like closed, deleted, or specific questions, then things get murky.  What would you propose as a good tag excerpt to avoid conflation, since it's worth discussing those individual pieces of moderation on their own?

Comment: Maybe a starting point is to look at cleaning up the tag-wiki's - then after that's done - see what's left that needs changing (if anything)...?

Comment: @JonClements & Makoto: thanks for your input, I've revised my proposal.