# Is a close vote causing the question to enter the close review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

When you cast a close-vote, does the action cause the question to enter the close review queue? Or only flagging a question does that?

IMO casting a close vote should add it in the queue as well - otherwise the question stays open with a single close vote, waiting for people with enough rep to cast a close/reopen vote as well and, in case of tags with only a handful of people following, that could take months (if not years).

Comment: Yes, a close vote does put it in the queue. Close votes expire as well so if you need votes on low traffic tags organize some users to regularly handle reviews in the CVQ for [that specific tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333311/578411). This is something more users might do by the way.

Comment: Note that it takes up to 15 minutes for a review task to be available after the first close flag or vote as the reviewtask creation job only runs every 15 minutes or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bottom of the [Cast Close & Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privileges page:

> **Any post which currently has an active close vote or a close flag will appear in the Close Votes review queue.** In this queue, users can either vote to close the question, edit the question, or recommend leaving it open. Edits or a sufficient number of "Leave Open" reviews will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the close votes. **If the question receives another close vote after being kicked out, it will re-enter the queue for further review.** Questions with vote to close as a duplicate will also list each possible duplicate in a tab at the top for easy reviewing.

(emphasis mine)

So yes, casting a close vote will cause the question to enter the review queue. Even if a question has been cleared from the queue, a new close vote will cause it to re-enter the queue.

Close votes *do* age away though; that 'feature' was introduced a few years back. If the question is not handled, or does not accrue another close vote or close flag, within 4 days, the close vote expires and you can re-cast your close vote. If you cast a close vote and the question is handled in the review queue, rather than expiring from the queue due to inactivity, then you cannot re-cast your close vote.